# Apache Permissions - not writeable

Tags: apache

I'm getting this error from my Apache server\

```
/var/www/PHP is not writeable by apache
```

make /var/www/PHP/data/files/ writeable by the user running the web server
in unix: 
chown daemon /var/www/PHP/data/files/; chmod u+w /var/www/PHP/data/files/

I gave permissions to all the directories and the itdb.db file

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try making those `chown -R` and `chmod -R` but it sounds like you've covered those already. You could try running apache in foreground mode with strace, i.e. `strace httpd -D FOREGROUND`, to see what it's trying to do when it raises the error?

Comment: Thanks Rup for your reply
this itdb.db permission set
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root